# Blender VFX Leaves Shadow Question

Tags: export

Hello I am currently working on a VFX series and in the scene I am working on I have a CGI Croagunk (a Pokemon) and he is in a forest I guess you could say so for the leaves casting shadows I rendered a musgrave texture rotating (I am also open to suggestions on another way I could do the leaves) I then imported the images into my scene to cast shadows onto croagunk as well as the shadow catcher. I am wondering how do I composite it so that croagunk remains in the scene and the leaves are not but their shadows are because when I render it the shadows that the leaves cast are there but the shadows on the plane appear in the scene. How do I get rid of those? Unfortunately I cant upload a picture on this but if you need one I can link you to my twitter.

Answer (score 0):

So I feel very stupid but unchecking camera in the object info tab did it.